# str_replace() adding an extra space to its input

Tags: php, sql, string, str-replace, quotes

Having a strange issue I can't figure out after several minutes of fiddling.

```
    $quotifiedValues = "'" . str_replace(",", "', '", $string) . "'";
```

I have this line to quote things ready for SQL.

Lets assume $string = "key, value".

$quotifiedValues = should become "'key', 'value'".

What it actually becomes though is "'key', ' value'".

The crucial thing here is the presence of an extra space. The word value is prefixed by an extra space. I have checked the inputs and, sure enough, no extra space is there. Yet I cannot eliminate it from the output of str_replace(). Any advice on what is going on is much appreciated.

Comment: Just a tiny suggestion: you should really be looking at prepared statements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make that

```
$quotifiedValues = "'" . str_replace(", ", "', '", $string) . "'";
```

Note that we replace `", "` now instead of `","`.

Comment: Not mentioned in the question but what if there's no space. The substitution would fail. -1.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`preg_replace`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php).

```
$string = "key  , value";
echo "'" . preg_replace("/\s*,\s*/", "', '", $string) . "'";
```

---

On a serious note, consider using prepared statements. Hacks like this can get you in trouble some day or the other.

Comment: Not mentioned in the question but what if there's no comma. The substitution would fail. -1. (not really)

Comment: SQL queries need a comma. Space is optional.